# Display time or any text on image with CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have an image on my page, I want to display some text on that image, in small black area, just like youtube do the same thing for video time in listing: http://www.youtube.com/charts

Youtube display "3.04" or similar time in video thumbs, I want to do the same thing, what will be the CSS and HTMl strcuture for the same.

Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RU5Dv/

```
<div class="imgblock">
  <img src="http://www.nataliedee.com/111908/whatever-dude-whatever.jpg">
  <div class="smallblackarea">3.04</div>
</div>

.smallblackarea {
    bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #FFF;
}

.imgblock {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
}

.imgblock img {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Z-index property in CSS.

> ```
>  <html>
>    <head>
>   <styletype="text/css">
>
> HTML, BODY {   margin: 0px;   padding:
> 0px;   border: 0px; }
>
> #the-outside {   border: solid 1px black;   background-color: gray;  
> width: 500px;   height: 400px; }
>
> #image-holder {   background-image: url(your-image.png);   z-index: 1;  
> position: absolute;   top: 0px;  
> left: 0px;   width: 500px;   height:
> 400px; }
>
> #text-holder {   z-index: 2;   position: relative;   top: 0px;  
> left: 0px; }
>
> </style> 
>  </head> 
> <body> 
> <div id="the-outside">
>  <div id="image-holder"><!-- image goes> here, "behind" the text --></div>  
> <div id="text-holder">
> <p>
>   Here is some text - and some more here too. 
>   Wheelbarrels are wonderful, aren't they?
> </p>
> <p>
>   Here is some text - and some more here too. 
>   Wheelbarrels are wonderful, aren't they?
> </p>
> <p>
>   Here is some text - and some more here too. 
>   Wheelbarrels are wonderful, aren't they?
> </p>
> <p>
>   Here is some text - and some more here too. 
>   Wheelbarrels are wonderful, aren't they?
> </p>   </div><!-- end text-holder --> </div><!-- end the-outside --> 
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```